# How do I pass the currentRecordId to the searchquery (Visualforce)

Tags: visualforce, soql, dynamic-visualforce

```
<apex:page extensions="SearchInVFShareholderVotes" standardController="Shareholder__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchKey}" label="Input"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Clear records" action="{!clear}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result {!currentRecordId}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!votes}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>


public with sharing class SearchInVFShareholderVotes {

    public list <Shareholder_Vote__c> votes {get;set;}
    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}    
    public String searchKey {get;set;}

    public SearchInVFShareholderVotes(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    }

    public void search(){
        string searchquery = 'Select Id, Name from Shareholder_Vote__c where AGM_Year__c like \'%'+searchKey+'%\'';
        votes = Database.query(searchquery);
    }
    public void clear(){
        votes.clear();
    }
}
```

When I change the query to

```
String searchquery = 'Select Id, Name from Shareholder_Vote__c where AGM_Year__c like \'%'+searchKey+'%\' AND Shareholder__c = :'+currentRecordId+'';
```

I get an error -

> Variable does not exist: a0ug0000003wIdXAAU Error is in expression
>   '{!search}' in component  in page
>   shareholdervotesvfpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dynamic SOQL, you don't need to enclose a string variable with single quote.
And I would suggest to also sanitise your search keywords before passing it into the query.

```java
String escapedSearchKey = '%'+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%';
String searchquery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Shareholder_Vote__c WHERE AGM_Year__c LIKE :escapedSearchKey AND Shareholder__c = :currentRecordId';
```